# Are the names Rollins, Morris, and Taylor in the novel "Daemon" a reference?

Tags: daemon

From the novel ["Daemon", by Daniel Suarez](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0525951113):

> The big guy regarded Mosely. “The fact that you're still alive is all I need to know about you.” He extended his hand. “I'm Rollins.” His eyes darted. “He's Morris.”
>
> Mosely regarded the hand. “Like I'm Taylor?”
>
> Rollins laughed. “Exactly like that.”

[Charles Taylor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Taylor_%28philosopher%29) is a real-life political philosopher.  Are the other two names in the quoted paragraph also references to real-life individuals? If so, who?

Comment: All I can think of is [Black Flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Flag_(band)).

Comment: Black Flag (led by Henry Rollins) have recorded songs featuring Keith Morris and Corey Taylor, but it seems like a bit of a stretch. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rise_Above:_24_Black_Flag_Songs_to_Benefit_the_West_Memphis_Three

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Keith Morris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Morris) and [Henry Rollins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Rollins) were both lead singers of [Black Flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Flag_%28band%29), a hardcore punk band from the mid-70s to mid-80s. [Corey Taylor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corey_Taylor) is the lead singer of [Slipknot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slipknot_%28band%29), a heavy metal band that could be seen as following along the path laid down by Black Flag.

This kind of follows the thread of the conversation in [*Daemon*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0525951113), grouping Morris and Rollins together and alluding to Mosely as being like Taylor, the new guy following up from their groundwork.

Comment: Sure, we'll go with that.